# Can string be output of the executed function directly into another string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have these 2 functions:

```
function takeOutTime(){
      return parseInt(document.getElementById("date").value.substr(8));
    }
    
function willWas(){
        if (new Date().getDate() >= takeOutTime() ){
        var a = "was"
      }else{
        var a = "will be"
      }
      return a
    }
```

And this code (`willWas()` is in there):

```
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "You selected "+ storedMovie + " which "+willWas()+" played " +storedDate+ " at "+storedTime;
```

The `willWas()` should output after refresh of the page "was" or "will be". When I call it in console output is correct.

But it doesn't change in the HTML after refresh.

What is wrong?

Comment: We need more to go off of. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: This has nothing to do with functions, strings, or interpolation. Updating the DOM is always only a one-off action, it does not provide a live, reactive binding. The code is not getting re-evaluated when dependencies (like current time or your date input) changes. You need to explicitly do that yourself. Install an `input` event listener.

Comment: Can we see your full code

Comment: `And this code`...and how exactly does that code get triggered? Because if it isn't triggered when the page is first loaded, then no it won't change after a refresh

Comment: @epascarello no errors - when I call willWas() in the console it outputs either "was" or "will be" just as I want. Problem is that it doesn't update in the text - last line of code.

Comment: Once the string is evaluated, it is done. if you want it to update, you would need to use setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: @epascarello But it works correctly when I get items from LocalStorage. I mean when you look at the last line of code its composed by storedMovie, storedDate, storedTime - and when I update these stored values and refresh the page it takes them and write them in the HTML on the page, the same I want to do with adding `" which "+willWas()+" played "`. Its output is changing correctly - but it writes only one output all the time `will be` . But in fact, when I execute it in console - output is changing correctly

Comment: Show all your code.....

Comment: when you reload the page, everything will be reset. so the value of element  with id="date" will be reset to its original. so you won't get a different behavior unless you come back to the page when that value is indeed less than current time.

Comment: @epascarello
https://codeshare.io/5v33wK

There it is. I load values from LS - so it should be already reloaded?

Comment: @Bergi But when I refresh the page other things changes according to LS and so on - why wouldn't this one thing change?

Comment: @RedemptionOkoro its in the comments

Comment: @ADyson its only triggered outside the function in this line of code above

Comment: @epascarello https://codeshare.io/5ObbdW This is the button, which is pressed and triggers functions and refreshes page - just to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I know what was the problem...

This line of code:

```
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "You selected "+ storedMovie + " which "+willWas()+" played " +storedDate+ " at "+storedTime;
```

should be after this one:

```
document.getElementById("movie").value = getSavedValue("movie");
document.getElementById("date").value = getSavedValue("date");
document.getElementById("time").value = getSavedValue("time");
```

Which loads the values - > so there was nothing to really compare.

Thank you all for afford, just beginners mistake. Shame on me!

Comment: @Bergi I normally try to look over the code couple of times and find out by myself - most of the time it works, but sometimes I'm just blind